# Como solucionar class, interface, or enum expected

Tags: java, clase

Quería probar si la copia de un JButton era igual al original. Así que intenté:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

JButton [ ] td1 = {new JButton("Ok"), new JButton ("Valider"), new JButton("Annuler") };
JButton [ ] td2 = td1;
System.out.println(td1[2]!=td2[1]);
```

Sin embargo, me sale los siguientes errores.

```
C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Pedro>javac annale2013.java
annale2013.java:6: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        JButton [ ] td1 = {new JButton("Ok"), new JButton ("Valider"), new JButton("Annuler") };
        ^
annale2013.java:7: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        JButton [ ] td2 = td1;
        ^
annale2013.java:8: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        System.out.println(td1[2]!=td2[1]);
        ^
3 errors
```

Comment: en tu array `td1` creas tres nuevos Jbutton. Luego creas la variable `td2` que apunta a `td1`. Ten en cuenta que no has clonado/duplicado los botones. Lo que has echo es hacer que `td2` apunte a la misma dirección en memoria al que apunta `td1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En el lenguaje Java no puede existir código fuera de una clase. Además, para que el código sea *ejecutable*, debes crear una clase que incluya un método `main` que es lo que la JRE buscará como *punto de entrada* (entry point)

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String ... args) {
        JButton [ ] td1 = {new JButton("Ok"), new JButton ("Valider"), new JButton("Annuler") };
        JButton [ ] td2 = td1;
        System.out.println(td1[2]!=td2[1]);
    }
}
```

Aunque tengas experiencia con otros lenguajes, te sugiero que busques un tutorial básico de Java para familiarizarte con los detalles poco intuitivos que puedas encontrarte en tus primeros pasos.

Comment: Si, tienes razon. Muchas gracias